# Hyperledger Composer: Error: Error trying login and get user Context. (code 20)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've been working through the Hyperledger Composer tutorials (specifically the developer one). I've hit a brick wall on this error code. From what I've found online, this is a "general network error" problem that could possibly be the result of some compatibility issues? With that being said, everything I've found isn't Hyperledger related. I'm still pretty new to this stuff.

Here's the tutorial I'm using:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/developer-tutorial

I was able to:

- Create a business network structure using Yeoman
- Define a business network (I made on the web-based playground tool, exported, and imported the .bna)
- Generate a business network archive
- Deploy the business network, create the admin card file for the network
- Import the network admin card

The network is showing up as an admin connection that I can connect to off of the PeerAdmin hlfv1 connection. I can connect to the network through my localhost, test around, view everything. No issues here.

However, when I try to ping the network with `composer network ping --card admin@<network name>`, I get thrown an error about the login and user context.

Here's the error:

```
Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
```

Command failed

I've seen a lot of threads for error 400, but none for error 20. Am I missing something here? Needless to say that since the network ping is throwing errors, I can't run `composer-rest-server` off of the network directory.

Here's my versions:

```
├── composer-cli@0.19.0
├── composer-playground@0.19.0
├── composer-rest-server@0.19.0
├── generator-hyperledger-composer@0.19.0
├── node-red@0.18.4
└── yo@2.0.1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have some mixed versions of composer with v0.19.0 of the cli and 18.2 for the other components.

There are many changes between 18.2 and v0.19.0 so you should upgrade everything to v0.19.0 with `npm uninstall -g` and `npm install -g`.

After that I would suggest creating a new Fabric by running the `startFabric.sh` script (and be sure that Fabric 1.1 starts).

I would also delete the folder ~/.composer, and then re-run the `createPeerAdminCard.sh`.

After these steps you should be OK to re-run the Developer tutorial.

Comment: So to be sure, I deleted the entire server instance and then started from scratch. I went through all of the steps and made sure that v0.19.0 of everything was installed. Fabric 1.1 started on startFabric.sh and I was able to run through all of the above steps as previously. I'm still getting the same error on composer network ping, though.

Comment: on the `composer network start` command, are you using adminand adminpw?  (You need to for the Development Fabric)

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm not having any issues getting the network started or running through some tests in the playground.

Comment: After you start the network you have a networkadmin.card file and you immediately import the card. And at this point the ping fails?  Or are you taking a copy of the .card file and using it 'later' ?